# .gitignore a file extension, but not a directory name

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following entry in .gitignore.

```
*.meta
```

Now this would be fine if only files would end in .meta.
 
Unfortunately, I have a directory `/ProtoBuf.Meta/`.
And now the entire content of ProtoBuf.Meta is ignored...

Is there a way to tell git that this gitignore directive is only for files, not directories ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

```
*.meta[!/]
```

or

```
!.meta/*
```

"!" negates the pattern